# Log user activity gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

i am about to create the functionality for logging user activity in my application. I was thinking of using observers and then log events through another model, something like UserLog.

Before doing that though, i would like to ask if there is already a good gem out there than can save me some time on this.

Do you happen to know any ?

p.s. btw, i am talking about custom defined user activity as well as logging ip addresses and so on. The first case of custom actions logging is more important though.

edit for clarity: I'm not referring to model changes but logging posted form variables and actions like this, not model changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[audited](http://rubygems.org/gems/audited)

audited is an ActiveRecord extension that logs all changes to your models in an audits table, with optional revision comments. acts_as_audited has been updated to work with Rails 3, to use it with older version of Rails .

Comment: I actually know of the gem but the problem is that i am not just talking about model changes. For instance, i would want to save the form options posted when a user submitted a form.